# How to add the space between two buttons which is defined in col-md-3 bootstrap grid system without using padding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to add space between two buttons which is defined inside the Boot strap grid system(col-md-3),It is working fine with padding-left but if i am checking for the responsive the second button is aligned to right by taking same padding.even though i have used media query as padding-left to 0px. its not working. please give me suggestion to make it responsive with space between the buttons which are defined inside two col-md-3 columns. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the width of your buttons to 80% and not 100% of the col. And then, center your buttons